Commutator of a subgroup is normal in the whole group
Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of some group $G$, then I aim to prove that $[H,H]=\langle h^{-1}k^{-1}hk \mid h,k\in H \rangle$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.
I’ve tried to use the same strategy of showing the commutator is normal, but when I take $g^{-1}cg=c[c,g],c\in [H,H]$ the conclusion doesn’t follow as $[c,g]$ might not be in $[H,H].$

Hint: show $g^{-1}[a,b]g = [g^{-1}ag,g^{-1}bg]$.

The commutator subgroup of $H$ satisfies a property stronger than normality: it is a characteristic subgroup of $H$, meaning that for every automorphism $\phi : H \to H$ we have $\phi[H,H]=[H,H]$. This is pretty easy to prove, using that $\phi(hkh^{-1}k^{-1}) = \phi(h) \phi(k) \phi(h)^{-1} \phi(k)^{-1}$.
So now take any $g \in G$, and consider the inner automorphism $i_g :G \to G$ defined by $i_g(c)=gcg^{-1}$ for any $c \in G$.
Using that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, it follows that the restriction $\phi = i_g \mid H$ is an automorphism $\phi : H \to H$.
And then it follows, from the first paragraph, that $i_g[H,H]=[H,H]$.

this seems like an overkill argument. we haven’t discussed automorphisms much in class, so I don’t have a strong grasp on the properties and consequences. Is there a more direct argument that looks at the normalizer?

You could show normality directly: take $g\in G$, then for any $h,k\in H$ you have $g(hkh^{-1}k^{-1})g^{-1}=(ghg^{-1})(gkg^{-1})(ghg^{-1})^{-1}(gkg^{-1})^{-1}$. and this is in $[H, H]$ because $H$ is normal. This shows the condition of normality for the generators of $[H, H]$, and I think you can argue yourself why it holds for the rest of the elements. This is @Lee Mosher 's argument but without the "automorphism" talk.

I wouldn't say it's overkill, although is a bit more abstract. On the other hand this solution motivates a broader understanding of what's going on. The key thing to take away from this solution, besides just solving the problem, is to learn about automorphisms and characteristic subgroups.

You may want to say "characteristic in $H$". (It is of course also fully invariant and verbal in $H$, but that is even more overkill....)
